# Converting a C file with c-strings to c++ strings

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a text based adventure game that needs to be re-vamped. Originally it was using c-style character pointers and now i'm required to convert it all to c++ strings. I'm working on a function that processes a command such as "move left, move right, move up, move down" and compares it to determine what prompt comes next. I've converted most of it but when I compare the strings it's not working right because the program outputs "I don't understand" when it should give the next prompt for the room. Below is where i'm having my issue.

```
enum Movement{
LEFT_CMD, RIGHT_CMD, UP_CMD, DOWN_CMD, 
NUM_COMMANDS //must be last
}; 

const char MovementToString[NUM_COMMANDS][SHORTSTRINGLENGTH] = {
 "left",
 "right",
 "up",
 "down"
};
bool parseCommand(std::string s, std::string t, eCommand& command, eItem& item){
bool found = false;
int i;

//parse command
for(i=0; i<NUM_COMMANDS && !found; i++)
found = strcmp(s.c_str(), ((char *)(commandToString[i]))) == 0;

if(found)command = (eCommand)(i - 1);
//parse item
bool found2 = true;
if(found){
  if(t.size() == 0)
    item = NONE_ITEM; //there are no items

else{ 
  found2 = false;
  for(i=0; i<NUM_ITEMS && !found2; i++)
    found2 = strcmp(t.c_str(), ((char *)(itemToString[i]))) == 0;
  item = found2? (eItem)(i - 1): NONE_ITEM;
} //else
}
```

Comment: Why not make `MovementToString` an array of `std::string`?\

Comment: I've tried, but with no luck

Comment: Please show what you tried which did not work.

Comment: @ColinO not-sure what you tried, but here's a working example: http://ideone.com/OAvcXq

Comment: This snippet won't output "I don't understand". Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The bool returns to main and if it returns false it goes to an else statement that says "I don't understand".

Comment: What is "the bool"? There are at least two variables with type `bool`: `found` and `found2`. At least why not show us the left part of the function?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you are asking, the function itself is also a bool.

Comment: The function returns nothing !  Start with a proper return statement. Then try to get rid of the char[][], the strcmp() and other c-string constructs.

Comment: A likely problem here is that the code calling `parseCommand()` is not passing it the strings you think it is.  You may want to insert some debugging `couts` in the function.  Even if the values look right, make sure there is no leading/trailing whitespace, newlines.   And yes, you should get rid of C-string constructs as @Christophe suggested.

Comment: `if(found){
  if(t.size() == 0)
    item = NONE_ITEM;` not closed with `}` before `else` starts

Comment: 1/ If you can use a C compiler to compile your C code, use the C tag. If you need to use a C++ compiler to compile your C++ code, use the C++ tag. **Don't use both!** 2/ Where's your MCVE? If we can't reproduce the problem you describe, **we can't help you fix it! Your code as it currently stands can't possibly print "I don't understand"** so we can't help you.

Comment: 3/ *"I've tried, but with no luck"*... Ahh, you tried X and failed... This made you think you need Y, and you failed with X+Y and hence asked about X+Y. You don't need Y, and you should've just asked about X (*not* X+Y) from the very start. See [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... In this case, you should've asked about *the error message* when you *tried, but with no luck*.